# java download script server side

Tags: nginx, download

I have a piece of code in javascript witch in localhost is working fine.

```
      if (id) {
        var y = new XMLHttpRequest();
        y.open("GET", "/dashboards/tb_gu_qs/crud_xml.php?key=" + id, true);
        y.responseType = 'blob';
        y.onload = function (e) { download(y.response, id + ".xml", "text/xml"); }
        y.send();
```

When i put them on server, i received a 500 error status
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yM9D.png)

My server is nginx
Thanks!

Comment: Need to provide more information about how this code is deployed and how the service is running on the target environment.

Comment: the code in apache2 works. I think the problem is even in some nginx configuration